# XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running?

Tags: linux, apache, unix, ubuntu, xampp

I have painfully analyzed all of yesterday if I had another apache/web-server instance running, with all of these commands

```
ps aux
ps -e
lsof 
netstat tunap
```

I DO NOT have another instance of Apache or ANY OTHER server running at port 8080.

Yet, XAMPP gives me this:

```
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running
```

What should I do?

I also edited httpd.conf to LISTEN to port 9876, and still the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If:

```
lsof -Pi |grep 8080        returns no results
netstat -na |grep 8080     returns no results
ps -ef                     shows no web server processes
```

Then maybe there's a lockfile lying around that the startup is checking against?  Those are typically found under /var/run but don't necessarily have to.  At this point I would usually run strace to see what's going on:

strace -e read=all -e write=all -f -o strace.out **your_startup_command**

Then open up strace.out, search for the "..is already running" string in the output, and starting looking at lines above it to see what is failing.

Answer (score 21):

```
 sudo rm /opt/lampp/logs/httpd.pid
// get listen pid
 sudo netstat -nap | grep :80
```

example of output:

```
tcp6   0  0 :::80  :::*  LISTEN  14417/httpd
```

PID is 14417

kill proc

```
 sudo kill 14417
```

start/restart lampp server

```
 sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Answer (score 9):

I didn't have any server running either, but I found this command that saved me:

```
sudo lsof -i :80
```

It displayed something like this for me:

```
COMMAND     PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Skype      4275    root   61u  IPv4 0x869da9d5a8e5506b      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

So killing Skype made it work.

Answer (score 7):

**Mind the port-check in start-script**

If you changed your xampp apache to listen to another port (/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf --> "Listen 80" is now "Listen 82"), then you also have to change the port-check in the /opt/lampp/xampp start script.

Just search in the /opt/lampp/xampp for the line with

```
'Another web server is already running.'
```

and search in the previous lines for:

```
if testport 80
```

change it to:

```
if testport 82
```

With that you can start an xampp on port 82 and keep your regular webserver on port 80 running.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd stop
```

This solution seems to work. You must restart lampp:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Solution tested for Ubuntu 12.04 after a similar problem.

Comment: Please reply in English.

Comment: I translated the solution you offered and It doesn't work

Comment: I don't know how to thank you for this... it worked Thank you..:)

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem disabling ssl port

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp disablessl
```

and then

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Answer (score 4):

Below command should work for me

```
  sudo service apache2 stop
```

then

```
  sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Answer (score 1):

The above solution didn't work for me. But this solution did -

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

And then restart apache, mysql if XAMPP GUI is available or restart from terminal (in Ubuntu) -

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that from a command shell using:

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep :80
```

In the last column you'll see: pid / process_name.You can use later, below command to stop the process:

```
 ps aux | grep process_name
```

after this try to restart lampp, using :: `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart`

Answer (score 1):

First just run `sudo xampp` it should show the list of available operations. If not, then there is a problem in xampp installation(It's another question).

Second run `sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run` This will open a GUI. In GUI you can start and stop server(apache, sql). It may work in most cases.

If it is not starting in GUI, then change the port. (There is an option to change the port in GUI). Now it may work.

If the GUI option doesn't work for you, then try next.

Option 1. Open `/opt/lampp/logs/error_log` file and read last 10 lines.

> In my case the error is `could not bind to address [::]:80` . This
> informs that port 80 is used by another service. Option are, change our
> apache server port at `GUI` or `/opt/lampp/properties.ini` file
> ("Sometimes you have to log-out of system and login again to work.")
> or stop the server that using this port.
>
> Hint: Here 80 is used so try 81 and so on..

Option 2. Do the following steps.

> Stop xampp `sudo xampp stop`
>
> then
>
> `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop`
>
> `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
>
> `sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd stop`
>
> then
>
> Start xampp `sudo xampp start`

**Note:-**
To remove `/etc/init.d/apache2` [How to remove Apache service](https://askubuntu.com/a/1150209/173227)

Answer (score -1):

Below command should work in all scenarios to stop Mysql services :

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

After tapping this start lampp service using below command :

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```