# when i try to run lamp server i got an unexpected error

Tags: xampp

i am using linux server 
i have installed xamp server 
and when i try to run ./opt/lampp/lampp status
i found 
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.2.3-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
on cli

and after that i use ./opt/lampp/lampp status
than the status is

Version: XAMPP for Linux 7.2.3-0
Apache is not running.
MySQL is not running.
ProFTPD is running.

how i can start the lampp now ?

Note:
i am not finding solution about port 8080 already running server 
but i am trying to connect with localhost/phpmyadmin or localhost/myproject using xampp
not localhost:8080

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037937/xampp-another-web-server-daemon-is-already-running)

Comment: What does this have to do with Kronos Workforce Central?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall xamp and than install latest version solved my problem.