# another web server is already running and unable to run Apache2

Tags: xampp, lamp, kali-linux

I am using **Kali linux**

I am unable to run **Apache2**, i tried so many ways to fix it .., i **successful** **installed** **xampp** and **apache2** but dont know why apache not running, **mysql** and **proFTD**  is **running**

When i run code to to check the status of apache in **lampp** it show that another web server is already running.

Comment: did you check this page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17037937/2299040?

Comment: Thanks error solved:)

Comment: Cool, please answer your own question or mark it as duplicate so that future reader can get help from this question :)

Comment: I got banned from posting question/answer how can i get out of an answer ban? please guide @SahilManchanda

Comment: can you share any screenshot explaining why you're banned?

Comment: Here is a useful link for you to read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/2299040

Comment: while answering getting this msg ("Some of your past answers have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from answering").

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(**another web server already runing**)

write this code in **terminal**

```
/opt/lampp/xampp disablessl
```

then **check** for the apache

```
sudo /opt/lampp/xampp start

Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.2.5-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
```